# Contando o número de operações executadas sobre uma mesma entrada para uma chamada recursiva

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

ideia: Comparar uma versão recursiva da implementação da exponenciação com a não-recursiva.

Versão recursiva:

```
def power(base,expoente):
    global cont

    if base == 1:
        return 1
    elif expoente == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        cont +=1
        return base*power(base,expoente-1), cont

#print(power(1,1000))
print(power(3,4))
```

A variável `cont` contaria o número de multiplicações.
Estou recebendo o erro:

```
NameError: name 'cont' is not defined
```

embora seja uma variável definida como global. O que está errado? Como contar o número de multiplicações efetuadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este erro está sendo gerado na linha em que você tenta o código `cont += 1`, pois em nenhum lugar do código você inicializou essa variável.

**Código corrigido:**

```
cont = 0

def power(base,expoente):
    global cont

    if base == 1:
        return 1
    elif expoente == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        cont +=1
        return base*power(base,expoente-1)

#print(power(1,1000))
print(power(3,4))
```

**Problema encontrado no seu código:**

Perceba que no código acima eu retirei o retorno da variável `cont`. Fiz isso porque não acho necessário retornar uma variável que é global e porque o retorno do `cont` estava causando um problema para seu código.

Basicamente, ao retornar o `cont`, você multiplicava uma tupla, pois a função retornaria dois valores. Logo a saída do código era essa:

```
((((3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4), 4, ((3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4), 4, ((3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4, (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4), 4), 4), 4)
```

Quando deveria ser essa:

```
81
```

**Código melhorado:**

```
def power(base, expoente):
    if base == 1 or not expoente:
        return 1
    else:
        return base * power(base, expoente - 1)
```

Se a variável `cont` não for usada durante a execução da função, eu não vejo necessidade em cria-la, pois ela terá o mesmo valor que o `expoente`.

Comment: Mas a minha lógica de contar as multiplicações está correta?

Comment: Sua lógica está correta mas o seu código possui um problema. Você está multiplicando uma tupla porque sua função retorna dois valores, sendo um deles a variável `cont`. Para solucionar este problema eu retirei o retorno do `cont`, até porque não faz muito sentido retornar uma variável que é `global` né.

Comment: Quando imprimo cont, ao final, dá zero... tem algo errado!

Comment: Para mim dá quatro. Você pode copiar e colocar o código exatamente como esta na minha resposta para verificar ?

Comment: em que parte do codigo eu posso imprimir o valor de cont?

Comment: Após a chamada da função. Se você imprimir antes, a saída realmente será zero pois a variável não teria sido alterada.

Comment: Meu codigo recursivo está pessimo: A contagem de multiplicacoes é a mesma que na versão não recursiva. Alguma sugestão para melhorá-lo?

Comment: Em relação a lógica não mas você pode dar uma simplificada nele, vou editar a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A variável `cont` está definida como `global`, mas deves inicializá-la previamente:

```
def power(base,expoente):
    global cont
    cont = 0
    if base == 1:
        return 1
    elif expoente == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        cont +=1
        return base*power(base,expoente-1), cont

print(power(3,4))
```

Comment: Mas a minha lógica de contar as multiplicações está correta?